# C++ strings, punctuation, arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need to be able to use only c++ strings in order to change the input paragraph below.  The issue I've run into is that when I pull something with punctuation at the end such as "programs-" it pulls it into my array as "programs-" instead of "programs" and "-" separately.  I need to know how to do this so that I can replace all the "-" with ".".

How does someone separate the two and place each in it's own block in the array?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


void read(string line[], string para[], int &d)
{
string temp;
int i = 0;

ifstream myfile ("paragraphwordsub.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( temp != "$" )
    {
        myfile >> temp;
        line [i] = temp;
        cout << line[i] << " ";
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    i=0;
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        myfile >> temp;
        para[i] = temp;
        cout << para[i] << " ";
        d++;
        i++;
    }

 myfile.close();
}

else cout << "Unable to open file";

cout << endl << endl << i << endl << para[73] << endl;

return;

}

int main()
{
  int const SIZE = 100;
  string a [SIZE];
  string b [SIZE];
  int counter = 0;

  read(a, b, counter);

  cout << endl << endl << counter << endl;


  return 0;

}
```

Input:

> Whose programs is such?
>       There were important programs to be done and Tommy were asked to do such-  Tommy were sure Sam would do such-  Samson could have done
>   such, but Nicholsonnders did such-  Sam got angry about that, because
>   such were Tommy's programs-  Tommy thought Samson could do such but
>   Nicholsonnders realized that Tommy wouldn't do such-  It ended up that
>   Tommy blamed Sam when Nicholsonnders did what Samson could have done-

Comment: I like how the example text makes no sense.

Comment: You can use `isalpha` function to check if a character is alphabetic or not.

Comment: The example text is supposed to not make sense since I will be replacing text in it with different text.  That includes changing all the "-"s to "." Neil, I'm not sure how I would do that using strings and pulling it from a file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand what you want to do with it but here is an example of how to tokenize the paragraph while keeping punctuation and spaces separate. I've used vectors instead of arrays but it should be easy to switch:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Words {
  std::vector<std::string> words_;
  bool lastCharacterIsAlphaNumeric_;

  void addAlphaNumeric(char character);
  void startNewWord(char character) {  words_.emplace_back(1, character); }
  void addNewWordForNonAlphaNumeric(char character);
  void clear() { words_.clear(); lastCharacterIsAlphaNumeric_ = false; }

public:
  Words() : lastCharacterIsAlphaNumeric_(false) {}
  void read(std::string filename);
  void print() { for(auto& word : words_) std::cout << word << std::endl; }
};

void Words::addAlphaNumeric(char character) {
  if (!lastCharacterIsAlphaNumeric_) {
    startNewWord(character);
    lastCharacterIsAlphaNumeric_ = true;
  } else {
    words_.back().push_back(character);
  }
}

void Words::addNewWordForNonAlphaNumeric(char character) {
  startNewWord(character);
  lastCharacterIsAlphaNumeric_ = false;
}

void Words::read(std::string filename) {
  clear();
  std::ifstream myfile (filename);
  char tmp;

  while(myfile.good()) {
    myfile.get(tmp);
    if(isalnum(tmp)) {
      addAlphaNumeric(tmp);
    } else {
      addNewWordForNonAlphaNumeric(tmp);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  Words words;
  words.read("paragraphwordsub.txt");
  words.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to find every occurrence of the substring "-" in your input and replace it with the substring ".".

You may have been hoping that because operator>> reads one "word" at a time from the input, it would stop after the last letter of "programs"; but actually it stops only when it comes to whitespace or the end of input. It seems desirable that there would be a stream manipulator you could use to tell it to stop at punctuation, but I don't know of any such manipulator.

You could try something like this:

```
myfile >> temp;
size_t position = temp.find("-");
while (found!=std::string::npos) {
  temp.replace(position, 1, ".");
}
```

If you use string variables instead of the literals "-" and ".", you can generalize this to make any substitution you want (but then instead of the constant 1 in the parameters of replace(), you must use the length of the substring to be replaced).